# Constructive Interference of two AC waveforms

Tags: waveform, phase

Is this correct?

We have two AC waveforms of the same phase.

1. 4000V 0.03 amps -> 120W
2. 12V 60 amps -> 720W

Total Watts 840W

If these two waves undergo constructive interference:
4012 * 60.03 -> 240,640W

Comment: I don’t know exactly what you’re doing here, but I do know it’s not correct. Are you stacking the supplies in series? If so the currents won’t add, they will be equal and limited by the lowest supply. If you’re putting them in parallel then there will be a fire.

Comment: It's just a thought experiment. What would the result be if you combine the two AC waves.

Comment: How would these waves combine? Are they radio waves or voltage on wires?

Comment: Voltage On wires.    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Allright. So there’s two ways to combine voltage sources - series and parallel connections. Furthermore there will be no current flow in the series case without a load attached, and in the parallel case one supply would be almost shorting out the other. I’m going to bed but if nobody beats me to it I’ll throw together some theory references and a simulation for you.

Comment: Does this pass the smell test?  From 840W, you propose 240kW.  If this applied, we'd be all over it.  Trust me, if it worked, we'd find uses for it.  So the assumption of constructive interference working for power waveforms seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The current of the waveforms is not related to the waveform, but to the current capacity of the supply that provides it. You can connect those two supplies in series, and you'll get 4012V limited to the *lowest* of the two currents, so 30mA. The power will still be around 120W.

You can connect the two supplies in parallel, and you'll likely blow the output stage of the lower voltage supply, since its output devices and capacitors won't be rated to take 4000V. You would need to add a high-voltage diode from the output of the 12V supply to the output of the 4000V supply. This would protect the 12V supply from being destroyed by the 4000V applied to its output. Then you'll get 4000V limited to 30mA, but if you draw more than 30mA, the voltage will drop to about 11V (12V minus a diode drop), until you exceed the diode current rating - likely much less than 60A. Then the output will drop to 0V.

There is no such thing as "constructive interference" of AC power supply outputs at low frequencies. They are AC voltages, but they won't interfere unless you configure them to be electromagnetic waves in free space or in a waveguide - like in a coaxial cable, or some other transmission line. For low frequencies plain old “telegraph wire” across the US would do.

The frequency will need to be high enough to provide a usable wavelength. Few people can afford an antenna that will radiate that 4000V signal at 60Hz, or the thousands of miles of thick coax cable it'd take to treat it as a waveguide at 60Hz. But if you can obtain an RF amplifier that can put 4000V RMS at 120W on the output, and another RF amplifier that can put 12V at 720W RMS on the output, then sure - you can couple them to free space or to a coax waveguide, and they'll interfere. The power doesn't mulitply, it will just add for constructive interference, with a matched load. With destructive interference, the power will be reflected towards the source, and will ordinarily destroy it: you'd need duplexers with terminations for the reflected energy, so that it could be safely disposed of.

The total power input into the system, and the total power coming out as radiation and heat are balanced and equal to each other. The most power you can get from your supplies is 840W, no matter what you do to the output. In fact, the more you manipulate the output, the more energy you’ll waste. Interference changes nothing in that regard.